# Removing an element when the contents are empty, but the hyperlink is active

Tags: javascript, html

I have a ul list that consists of hyperlinks followed by text. I would like to use javascript to remove any li that has a hyperlink, but is not followed by actual text.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://x.x.com/employee/ts2"</a>ts2</li>
<li><a href="http://x.x.com/mission_support"</a></li> <---**problem LI**
<li><a href="http://x.x.com/News"</a>News</li><br>
</ul>
```

How can I use javascript to remove the `"<li><a href="http://x.x.com/mission_support"</a></li>"` line from the ul? I've tried multiple jquery examples that others asked on this site and for whatever reason my site is ignoring the jquery. I'm hoping javascript will yield better results.

Note: This should not be considered a duplicate question, since I am explicitly asking for this result in Javascript and not in Jquery.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I updated my ul & li so that they are valid html. I think the reason none of the jQuery examples or the javascript examples posted below are working is because of the fact that a hyperlink is in between

so in a sense the element is not empty. If that is the case how can I make it where if there is not any following text ie:

```
<li><a href src='www.test.com'></a>LINK NAME</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: On first look, your HTML is invalid, it should be like `<ul> <li><a href='www.link.com'>Link #1</a></li></ul>`, Anchors should be under `li`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Anchors can't be direct children of `<ul>` elements.

Comment: "my site is ignoring the jquery" Go after that problem first.

Comment: stackrack: You say your site is ignoring your jQuery, but then you say you're asking for it "not in jQuery".

Comment: @BlueSkies, before I asked my question I checked the site for others having a similar problem. I tried the jQuery examples, but my page would not acknowledge the code. Even the alert('test'); will not fire, but the javascript of the alert works.

Comment: I did not know the HTML was invalid as the links display and are working properly. I'll try changing the order first and see if that makes a difference. I'll report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    if(el[i].innerHTML == "")
    {                       
        el[i].parentNode.removeChild(el[i]);
    }
};
```

This will remove all such empty nodes.

Answer (score 0):

First write a valid HTML code. I have done it for you. Here is JavaScript solution

http://jsfiddle.net/alaminopu/ttvv9/

HTML :

```
<ul id="links">
<li><a href='www.link.com'>Link #1</a></li>
<li><a href='www.zoo.com'>Link #2</a></li>
<li><a href='www.fox.com'></a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("links");
var li =ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[2];
li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
```